# record generated by FactoryGirl disappears in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

We are running a spec (3.4.4) with Rails 4.2.0. Here is the spec:

```
  it "returns http success" do
    proj = FactoryGirl.create(:ext_construction_projectx_project, :name => 'namenewnew')
    get 'new' , {:project_id => proj.id}
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
```

In debug, `proj.id` is `3` and all its values are correct. `ExtConstructionProjectx::Project.find(3)` returns `nil` and `ExtConstructionProjectx::Project.count` returns `0`. The project record just disappears.

Is it possible that the rspec did not see the `project` record created on its db connection? How to fix this problem?

Update:

Here is the gemspec

```
  s.add_dependency "rails", ">=4.2.0"
  s.add_dependency "jquery-rails"
  s.add_dependency "simple_form"
  s.add_dependency "will_paginate"
  s.add_dependency "database_cleaner"
  s.add_dependency "execjs"
  s.add_dependency "sass-rails", '~>5.0.1'
  s.add_dependency "coffee-rails", '~>4.1.0'   
  s.add_dependency "uglifier"

  s.add_development_dependency "sqlite3"
  s.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails", ">= 3.2.0"
  s.add_development_dependency "factory_girl_rails", '~>4.5'
  s.add_development_dependency 'capybara'
  s.add_development_dependency 'launchy'
```

Also in `rails_spec`, there is:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Comment: This is a controller spec, correct? Are you using database cleaner? Does `config.use_transactional_fixtures` equal `false` in your `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: Are you using something like database_cleaner to clean the database out between runs? How are you debugging this? (you do realize that tests and the dev console use different databases?)

Comment: `Anthony E`, `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` in `rails_spec`. Also in `gemspec`, there is `s.add_dependency "database_cleaner"`

Comment: `max`, yes, I used `s.add_dependency "database_cleaner"` in `.gemspec`. I am using Rubymine 2016 for debug.

Comment: Yes, it is a controller spec. The engine is being updated and the previous spec passed.

Comment: Does `proj.persisted?` return true or false? How about `proj.valid?` ?

Comment: `Andy Waite`, both `proj.persisted?` and `valid? return `true`.

Comment: What's the SQL in your log/test.log?

Comment: What is your first problem? Does the spec fail? How? Also, what does `...::Project.count` return when you run it from within the spec (not from the debugger)? Note that since the spec runs within a database transaction, only the spec's db connection will see the records it created.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you `require 'factory_girl_rails'` in your `rails_helper.rb` and also make sure it says this? ```ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

 RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods``` and have everything in spec/factories/xxx.rb ?

Comment: If you are using DatabaseCleaner then your database will be truncated after every "it" block.
I hope you are trying to debug inside the "it" block.

Comment: can you post your FactoryGirl file where `ext_construction_projectx_project` is defined?

Comment: Some suggestion on debug this test failure: check the response.body and status code to see if it shows any error. You can do that by adding a `expect(response.body).to eq('certainly not this')` below the `get new` line. That would help you figure something out if the real issue is not related to db persistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If database records persisted between test calls, your testing wouldn't be isolated or properly test each case.

#### If you don't want the current behavior:

- Consider removing (or reconfiguring) the [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem.
- Set `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` in your rspec configuration. Or review the [rspec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions) for another strategy.

#### The "better" solution:

- **Rewrite your tests such that they do not depend on state from earlier test runs.**
- Consider using `before(:each)` and `before(:all)` macros in your rspec tests.